# How to sort objects in ArrayList by 2 float attributes?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I aim to sort an arraylist of a class

```
 public class AnimSprite
    {
    float x,y,z;
    //...//
    }

ArrayList<AnimSprite> listofsprites = new ArrayList<AnimSprite>();

    //...//

list.add( new AnimSprite(1f,10f,0f) );      //x,y,z
list.add( new AnimSprite(15f,25f,1f) );
list.add( new AnimSprite(30f,-62f,0f) );
list.add( new AnimSprite(150f,-62f,2f) );
list.add( new AnimSprite(55f,-65f,0f) );

    //...//
```

Then of course I loop to draw it

```
for (AnimSprite s: listofsprites) { s.draw();}
```

Before draw instruction, how could we sort the array list ?
*(ordered by y ascending and then z ascending)*

Eg expected result:

```
obj0 -> AnimSprite(55f,-65f,0f)
obj1 -> AnimSprite(30f,-62f,0f) 
obj2 -> AnimSprite(1f,10f,0f)
obj3 -> AnimSprite(15f,25f,1f)
obj4 -> AnimSprite(150f,-62f,2f)
```

for the moment, as below, I sort ascending by y and z but I am not sure it is state of art?

```
  public static class AnimSprite implements Comparable<AnimSprite >
    {
    //...//
   Override
       public int compareTo(AnimSprite o)
    {
        float result = this.z - o.z;
        if (result == 0f) result = this.y - o.y;
        return ((int)(result));
        }
```

Comment: I suggest you to try it yourself using the `Comparator` interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html. If you still have a hard time, pls reply and we can work through it.

Comment: It's not topic itself, but I would suggest to use interface instead of classes where possible, for example: ArrayList<AnimSprite> listofsprites = new ArrayList<AnimSprite>(); should be List<AnimSprite> listofsprites = new ArrayList<AnimSprite>();

Comment: thanks but the final point is sorting by 2 floats

Comment: `Collection.sort(list)`

Comment: Please focus on sorting by 2 float attributes properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Collection.sort(list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) to sort your `ArrayList` but `AnimSprite` must implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) Interface to let the `sort` method to know how to compare two `AnimSprite` objects.

```
public class AnimSprite implements Comparable
{
    float x,y,z;
    //...//

   @Override
   public int compareTo(AnimSprite o)
{
    float result = this.z - o.z;
    if (result == 0f) result = this.y - o.y;
    return ((int)(result));
    }   
}

ArrayList<AnimSprite> listofsprites = new ArrayList<AnimSprite>();

    //...//

listofsprites.add( new AnimSprite(1f,10f,0f) );      //x,y,z
listofsprites.add( new AnimSprite(15f,25f,1f) );
listofsprites.add( new AnimSprite(30f,-62f,0f) );
listofsprites.add( new AnimSprite(150f,-62f,2f) );
listofsprites.add( new AnimSprite(55f,-65f,0f) );

//...//

Collection.sort(listofsprites);

for (AnimSprite s: listofsprites) { s.draw();}
```

Another solution is to use the overloaded method `sort` that accept the `Comparator` implementation as second argument, and use the [`Lambda expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to write less code:

```
Collections.sort(listofsprites, (s1, s2) -> {
    float result = s1.z - s2.z;
    if (result == 0f) result = s1.y - s2.y;
    return ((int)(result));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I moved forward with comparable interface. However I can't figure simpliest way for 2 attributes sorting (eg y and z)?

Comment: @Chronoslog see my edit: I implemented your comparing logic inside the lambda

Comment: I will go to first option more efficient in terms of response time M1> **291537 nanoSecs** (@Override ... compareTo(AnimSprite o)) whereas 
M2> 48145753 nanoSecs (Collections.sort(listofsprites, (s1, s2) -> ...)

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways to achieve what you want. Both boil down to the idea that the elements of the array should be "comparable" to each other.

**Option 1:**

Implement `Comparable` interface in `AnimSprite`. Define `compareTo` method (that you'll have to since you implement the interface) to rely on 2 numbers for comparison.

Then use:

```
Collections.sort(yourArray);
```

**Option 2:**

Can be used when you can't really change `AnimSprite` class. In this case you can implement the `Comparator` interface effectively externalizing comparison logic:

```
Collections.sort(yourArray, new Comparator<AnimSprite> {
     public int compare(AnimSprite s1, AnimSprite s2) {
                ...
     }
 });
```

Of course you can also use lambda if you're using java 8+

Comment: sorry question is not how to sort java object but specific to by 2 floats (not Integer, or String or whatever...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can also do something like this:

```
    Collections.sort(list,
            Comparator.comparing((AnimSprite a) -> a.z)
                    .thenComparing((AnimSprite a) -> a.y));
```

Comment: thank you it works but execution times seams longer: M1> 291537 nanoSecs (@Override ... compareTo(AnimSprite o))
M2> 48145753 nanoSecs (Collections.sort(listofsprites, (s1, s2) -> ...)
M3> 48187767 nanoSecs  (  Comparator.comparing((AnimSprite a) -> a.z ....thenComparing ...)